# How to unescape escaped regex?

Tags: regex, go

I'm looking for the reverse of [regexp.QuoteMeta](https://godoc.org/regexp#QuoteMeta).
  Is it there a such function?

I've tried to manually unescape it using `strings.Replace("\", "", -1)` but this is prone to error/unreliable as it doesn't work in all the cases(i.e. on excessive escaping or unicode).

I also tried to add some quotes and use  [strconv.Unquote](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) `(e.g. strconv.Unquote(`"`+ "https:\/\/ad.doubleclick.net" +`"`) )` but it errors out.

Comment: No there is no such function. Did you take a look at a Regexps string method?

Comment: String() doesn't seem to work ... it prints the escaped string (`https:\/\/ad.doubleclick.net`)

Comment: The regexp.QuoteMeta function will not return the string `https:\/\/ad.doubleclick.net` for any input.  Please update the question with the actual strings and code.

Answer (score 3):

Parse the string with the [regexp/syntax](http://godoc.org/regexp/syntax) package to get the unquoted string:

```
func unquoteMeta(s string) (string, error) {
    r, err := syntax.Parse(s), 0)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    if r.Op != syntax.OpLiteral {
        return "", errors.New("not a quoted meta")
    }
    return string(r.Rune), nil
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/O8WetXgHiz)